# Is it possible to activate virtualenv in Google-colab? (/bin/sh: 1: source: not found)

Tags: virtualenv, theano, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install theano in Google Colab for testing. I have installed `virtualenv` and created an environment:

```
!pip3 install virtualenv
!virtualenv theanoEnv
```

But am not able to activate the virtual environment even explicitly mentioned the location of 'activate' command.

```
!source /content/theanoEnv/bin/activate theanoEnv
```

Error Message is:

```
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
```

Is it even possible to do?:

```
source /[SomeVirtualEnv]/bin/activate SomeVirtualEnv
```

Answer (score 16):

> Basically each ! command runs in its own shell, and Colaboratory does not know the environment changed

I figured out a workaround for this. Since each shell is temporary, we stitch the environment activation command and the command to be executed in environment.

So after you do

```
!pip3 install virtualenv
!virtualenv theanoEnv
```

you can install theano in the environment by

```
!source /content/theanoEnv/bin/activate; pip3 install theano
```

Since the environment contents are stored on disk in theanoEnv directory, it is preserved. But you need to activate it for each new shell.
For every command you need to run in the environment, simply prefix it with

```
!source /content/theanoEnv/bin/activate;
```

For example, to get a list of installed python packages (i.e. to run `pip3 list`) in environment, run:

```
!source /content/theanoEnv/bin/activate; pip3 list
```

You can stitch multiple commands this way: (all of them will be executed in the same shell)

```
!source /content/theanoEnv/bin/activate; COMMAND1; COMMAND2; COMMAND3
```

You can check my notebook on Colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Vg005uKhgt-ZwyQ11-BGceqY0q07qIzF).

Comment: not too sure why, but I get this error on Colab `'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Could you provide a link to a sample notebook demonstrating it, preferably with edit permissions?

Comment: This allows to install packages in a venv but how can you make all the following python code to use this venv? i.e. after `!  pip install robotframework; pip list;
from robot import run` it still falls back to it's default environment which does not have the robot module --> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot'`.

Comment: I think as a workaround one can put his code in a .py file and when do something like  `!source /content/venv/bin/activate; pip install robotframework; pip list; \
!  python ./my_code.py`

Comment: I am not sure why you are using "from" command. I checked its manpage and description says "print names of those who have sent mail".  You probably mean `python -m "from robot import run"`.  
`!source /content/venv/bin/activate; pip install robotframework; pip list; python -m robot --help` successfully prints help message for me, using linked notebook.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer, I don't believe it is possible, although you can always run

```
!pip3 install theano
```

I was able to activate the virtualenv, but I don't believe you can switch the current notebook to use the newly created virtualenv.

```
!pip3 install virtualenv
!virtualenv theanoEnv
!echo '#!/bin/bash \n . ./theanoEnv/bin/activate theanoEnv \n which python3'  > source_theanoEnv.sh && chmod +x source_theanoEnv.sh && ./source_theanoEnv.sh && which python3
!which python3
```

I have put "which python3" in 3 places and the results are

```
/content/theanoEnv/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

So it looks like the "activate" is only temporary and Colaboratory/Jupyter are using /usr/bin/python3 still

Basically each ! command runs in its own shell, and Colaboratory does not know the environment changed

I was hoping I could follow these steps
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs/

```
/content/theanoEnv/bin/pip3 install ipykernel
/content/theanoEnv/bin/python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=theanoEnv
```

But I don't know what to set the kernel_class to

```
%config IPKernelApp.kernel_class='???'
```

Also, even if the above worked, I don't believe there is a way to restart the notebook to use the new kernel.

Perhaps someone more versed in Jupyter/Colaboratory could explain if this would be possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can update `sys.path` to use virtualenv packages from within your current Colab session:

```
!pip install virtualenv
!virtualenv theanoEnv
!theanoEnv/bin/pip install theano
import sys
sys.path.append("theanoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages")
```

With `sys.path` updated, you can now import theano without any further hacks:

```
import theano
```

I should note that the path above assumes that Colab will always be running Python 3.7. You can obviously use more sophisticated code to locate the `site-packages` subdirectory under the `theanoEnv/lib/` directory, regardless of which version of Python is being used.

Comment: Use `site.addsitedir` instead of `sys.path.append` in order to account for `egg-link` files installed using `setuptools` '  `develop` option

Answer (score 1):

try to run this command

```
!sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

or try this package

```
https://pypi.org/project/colab-env/
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it