# Google Colab: WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager

Tags: python, virtualenv, google-colaboratory, python-venv

```
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

I get the above WARNING while trying to pip install certain packages in Google Colab. I got this WARNING on executing the following line of code:

```py
!pip uninstall -y enum34 && pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel && apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
```

The warning statement says, to use a virtual environment. How can I setup a Virtual Environment in Google Colab with the `venv` module? I didn't find an accepted/satisfactory solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48512569/12247181).

Also is there any better way, to solve the warning( I wish to solve it, not just get rid of it for namesake.)

Comment: strange, I never see this warning when I run `!pip install` in Google Colab

Comment: maybe you should try `!pip install --user ...`

Comment: @furas I got the WARNING statement, on installing certain packages. I have included the code to reproduce this warning in the Question.

Comment: you could split line to separated commands and see which one makes problem - probably `update pip`

Comment: Same here. The solution pointed is to use a virtual package manager. The problem is that the shell commands ipython in  are executed in a separate shell, and when the comand is finished, the update to the PATH variable is lost.